# Azure QnAMaker - Managing Content

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I have a couple of questions regarding the QnAMaker service from Azure Cognitive services -

1. For adding KB articles, does it support adding SharePoint Online Url directly?.
2. Is there a way to use an API route to submit documents. The API reference [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/5ac266295b4ccd1554da75ff) does not seem to provide an easy route. I can add Q&A pairs but I want the QnA service to identify Q&A's from the document by itself.
3. As I understand, the data plane for QnAMaker is Azure Search, can we leverage Azure to crawl the data, and then we use QnAMaker to surface the data?.
4. Currently, QnA maker does not seems to support auto-extraction of non-public URLs. Can we extend this facility?.

Answer (score 0):

The QnA Maker doesn't support adding SharePoint Online URLs directly as it parses only public URLs and does not support authenticated data sources as per the [documentation](https://www.qnamaker.ai/old/Documentation/Faqs).

> The tool parses only public URLs and does not support authenticated
>   data sources at this time. Alternately, you can download the file and
>   use the file-upload option to extract questions and answers.

So, if you want to auto-extract non-public URLs, you'll have to download them and use the file-upload option to extract questions and answers.

Comment: Thanks Ali. So there were 1 questions around URLs. I believe you have responded to point 4 in the question. If yes, I was hoping there is a way to customize the process.

Comment: You're welcome, and yes, I responded to 1 and 4, and to customize the process, maybe you can create a solution where SharePoint is authenticated and use the [Update Knowledgebase API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/5ac266295b4ccd1554da7600).

Comment: The Update API does not support sending a document, but Q&A pairs. If I have to extract Q&A from unstructured documents, that's like setting up an NLP facility at my end. I was hoping to leverage the extraction from the QnAMaker and train as needed.

Answer (score 0):

QNAMaker now supports adding a secured SharePoint data source to your knowledgebase.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/add-sharepoint-datasources